# SPARQL querying not possible

Tags: fuseki, turtle-rdf

I installed Fuseki on my local Ubuntu. Accessible via http://localhost:3030. Added a dataset "fuwstats" and a named graph "fuwstats" and then I imported some triples (see code below).
When I want to run the standard SPARQL query, nothing is shown (0 results). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

SPARQL Endpoint is: `http://localhost:3030/fuwstats/query`

Query is: `SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }`

This is the RDF that I added to the dataset:

```
@prefix fuwarticle: <http://localhost/article/> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

fuwstats:1452406 dc:source fuwarticle:lonza-stellt-sich-neu-auf.
fuwstats:1452406 fuwstats:visit _:b.
_:b fuwstats:visitor "bbbbbbbbbb"^^xsd:int.
_:b dcterms:date "2019-02-25 10:37:10"^^dcterms:W3CDTF .
fuwstats:1452406 fuwstats:visit _:c.
_:c fuwstats:visitor "aaaaaaaaa"^^xsd:int.
_:c dcterms:date "2019-01-26 10:37:10"^^dcterms:W3CDTF .`
```

Comment: Try 'SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o.}}'  in case there is no default union graph.

Comment: thank you. it works. does it mean my rdf is not well-formed?

Comment: No, if it wasn't correct it wouldn't have loaded. It just means your Fuseki configuration doesn't create a default graph as a union of all named graphs in the dataset. Therefore you have to specify a named graph or a variable for all graphs in your queries. See the Fuseki docs on assembler files and the unionDefaultGraph property